# ndb.ComputedProperty causes 'RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded'

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

This is my class `Stat`. I am adding a new compute property to the class which will automatically sum up various counts in the existing class

```
class Stat(ndb.Model):
   visit_count = ndb.IntegerProperty(default=0)
   exit_count  = ndb.IntegerProperty(default=0)


   # New code
   def _get_total_count(self):
      return self.visit_count + self.exit_count

   response_count = ndb.ComputedProperty(lambda self: self._get_total_count)
```

When I create an instance of this class and save it

```
stat = Stat(visit_count=0, exit_count=2)
stat.put()
```

I get this exception:

```
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py", line 1207, in _value_to_repr
    return repr(val)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py", line 3013, in __repr__
    rep = prop._value_to_repr(val)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py", line 1207, in _value_to_repr
    return repr(val)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py", line 3013, in __repr__
    rep = prop._value_to_repr(val)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py", line 1207, in _value_to_repr
    return repr(val)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py", line 3013, in __repr__
    rep = prop._value_to_repr(val)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py", line 1207, in _value_to_repr
    return repr(val)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py", line 3013, in __repr__
    rep = prop._value_to_repr(val)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py", line 1207, in _value_to_repr
    return repr(val)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/ndb/key.py", line 357, in __repr__
    if self.app() != _DefaultAppId():
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/ndb/key.py", line 824, in _DefaultAppId
    return os.getenv('APPLICATION_ID', '_')
  File "/Users/antkong/dev/zeetings/zeetings-ve/bin/../lib/python2.7/os.py", line 515, in getenv
    return environ.get(key, default)
  File "/Users/antkong/dev/zeetings/zeetings-ve/bin/../lib/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 58, in get
    def get(self, key, failobj=None):
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

If I remove the compute property, `put` can be executed without issue.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
response_count = ndb.ComputedProperty(lambda self: self._get_total_count)
```

Means that the value you're returning for your `ComputedProperty` is the *function* `self._get_total_count` - you're not calling it.

```
response_count = ndb.ComputedProperty(lambda self: self._get_total_count())
```